# Lyx - Appendix problem

Tags: lyx

If I add an appendix at the end of my document, for example after the Bibliography, by choosing Chapter, Lyx will display Appendix A, what I do not want, as I have only one Appendice and I want to display Appendice (without the A). So, I select Chapter*, then I type Appendice, and in the PDF, the title Bibliography will appear in top of all pages of the Appendice.

Comment: Do you use [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)? What `\documentclass` are you using? Do you have sections in your appendix?

Comment: What other effect(s) do you want to achieve, besides having only one "Appendix"? Do you want to have the Appendix before Bibliography?

Comment: @Werner Document class is "book(more font sizes)". For hyperref I don't know, where can I check that ? I don't have sections in my appendix, just one chapter.

Comment: @Kevin C No other effect, just the appendix after the bibliography (if I remove the bibliography it does the same thing but with the last chapter instead: I get chapter 6 title in top of the appendix pages in the pdf).

Comment: @Gilbert: Are you using BibTeX to generate the bibliography? I don't have the issue you described when I put the bibliography *before* the appendix chapter. Are you using headers/footers? It may help other people to spot your problem if you can include a screen shot of the PDF output, you LyX editing interface, and the preamble of your document. BTW, to see if you've enabled `hyperref`, go to `Document`>`Settings..` and check either (i) under `PDF Properties` if `Use hyperref support` is checked; or (ii) under `LaTeX Preamble` if there is anything like `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Comment: @KevinC I checked hyperref: nothing in the settings nor in the preamble. See http://abobo188.imgur.com/all/ for pictures of the problem.

Comment: @Gilbert: I can't open the link you provided. But does the answer below solve your problem?

Comment: Wonderful, it works !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically the same problem as [Headers of \chapters* take the headers of their previous \chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78088/headers-of-chapters-take-the-headers-of-their-previous-chapter)

Right after the chapter heading, add an ERT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, and write

```
\markboth{Appendice}{}
```

If you have added `twoside` as an option to the document class, the first argument (`Appendice` in the example above) is printed in the header of even (verso) pages, while the second argument (empty) is printed on the odd (recto) pages.