# While using fancy header, when using \chapter*, header takes previous chapter heading

Tags: header-footer

I want to change the font style of right header. while using \chapter*, right header show the chapter heading of the previous chapter.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\DeclareFixedFont{\chapternumberfont}{T1}{ppl}{m}{n}{1.5in}

\newcommand\brectangles{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\fill[red!60!blue!50!green!120]%[red!60!blue!50!green!150]% 
  (current page.north west) rectangle ( $ (current page.north east) + (0,-7cm) $);
\fill[red!60!blue!50!green!120]%[red!60!blue!50!green!150]% 
  (current page.south west) rectangle ( $ (current page.south east) + (0,3cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Large\bfseries\ssfamily\color{white}}%\scshape
  {\thispagestyle{empty}\brectangles}
  {-2in}
  {%
  \vskip-4ex\filcenter {\small\MakeUppercase{Project on Compilation of...}}\\[2ex]
  \parbox[b]{.65\linewidth}{#1}%
  \raisebox{0.8in}{\parbox{.15\linewidth}{\large\chaptertitlename}}%
  \parbox[b]{.2\linewidth}{\chapternumberfont\thechapter}%
  }
  [\vspace*{1in}]

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries\color{white}} %sffamily\
  {\thispagestyle{empty}\brectangles} 
  {-2in}
  {\parbox[b]{.65\linewidth}{#1}}
  [\vspace*{1in}]


% for fancy header & footer
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Statistics}
\lfoot{ LHS }
\rfoot{\includegraphics[width=20pt]{logo}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}


%for quotes
\usepackage{csquotes}

% for hyperrefrences
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=blue
}

% for line spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

%for indenting paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

%for drop caps
% works with pdfLaTeX
\usepackage{type1cm} % scalable fonts
\usepackage{lettrine}

% FOR CALLIGRAPHIC FONTS
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{roman}

\pagestyle{empty}% no page numbers

\pagestyle{plain}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter {Introduction}

\clearpage

\section{Right header is in capitals, how to change in normal font}

\section {Background}

\chapter*{Appendicies}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendicies}

\section*{Appendix-W.R}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix-Workers' Remitances}

\clearpage

\newpage

\section{Ahmad}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Headers of `\chapter*` take the headers of their previous `\chapter`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78088/5764)

Comment: I think it's not a duplicate actually; rather, Ahmad just needs to use the `\appendix` command properly and all will be fine. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using appendices in the wrong way, and this is causing you problems, hence the need for all your `\addcontentsline` faff. When you've finished your normal chapters, put the `\appendix` command. Then carry on making more chapters and sections as before. Chapters in the appendix will be labelled as *A*, *B*, etc, and the sections will be labelled *A.1*, *A.2*, *B.1* and so on.

### Code

```
\chapter {Introduction}

\clearpage

\section{Right header is in capitals, how to change in normal font}

\section {Background}

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix-Workers' Remitances}

\section{Ahmad}

\section{Ahmad again}

\chapter{Ahmad yet again}

\section{Ahmad once more}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: thanks for correction john, this is my first document in Latex. Could you please fix the header's font issue to?

Comment: You mean the fact that "Project on Compilation of..." is capitalised?

Comment: no no, in right header it is showing CHAPTER 2. INTRODUCTION , i want to show only the name "Introduction" like this.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure. You'd better ask a new question. This site works best with the "one issue per question" rule of thumb.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, just simply add:

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
\markboth{}{Introduction}
```