# Problem with Table of Contents and Chapter on Introduction

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, thesis

I am currently writing my final master thesis in tex. I am stuck up in the following place. Firstly I have a chapter called Introduction which is not numbered. In the table of contents page, the introduction page starts with a different page number than 1. Ex:[image]

Next problem is in the introduction chapter. The heading is different from what it supposed to be. In my template, the first page of the chapter only has a header line with page number and the subsequent pages have the chapter name as header. In this case it is throwing up something else. Ex.
[image]

and this is the next page
[image]

How to resolve this ?

The third problem is in the table of contents as shown in the figure, "Acknowledgements" and "Abstract" have been assigned some roman numbers. But actually there are no page numbers in the respective tex files. How to set page numbering for these two pages and also incorporate the same in the table of contents. I am also attaching my code in the main file thesis.tex so that it is helpful:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{book}
% Start Global Settings
\linespread{1.3}
%\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{attrib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
%\usepackage{nath}
%\usepackage{w}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%use color for the document
\usepackage{color}
%for allowing word-wrap around images.
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{xunicode}
%\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
%\font\serif="FreeSerif:script=beng"
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Devanagari}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%Indent the first line of the first paragraph after each section heading.
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%Enable HyperLinks
\usepackage[plainpages=false]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} %By doing this, we allow subsubsubsections to be numbered :)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}

    \fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \fancyhf{} % delete current setting for header and footer
    \fancyhead[L]{\bfseries\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[R]{\bfseries\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
    \addtolength{\headheight}{1pt} % make space for the rule
    \fancyfoot[L]{\bfseries \it{\bfseries{}}}       %footer here
    }

%   %LOOKS LIKE THE FANCY HEADER USES PLAIN FANCYPAGESTYLE FOR THE FIRST PAGE OF EACH CHAPTER.
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}% get rid of headers on plain pages
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries \thepage}
    }

    \fancypagestyle{empty}
    {
        \fancyhf{}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    }
%End Global Settings

%\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
%\setlength{\topskip}{0.3in}    % between header and text
\setlength{\textheight}{8.4in} % height of main text
%\setlength{\textwidth}{5.8in}    % width of text
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.75in} % odd page left margin
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.75in} % even page left margin

%\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-2cm}
%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-2cm}
%\addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}  
\pagestyle{empty}

\input{Title.tex}
% !TeX program = xelatex
\input{dedication2.tex}
\input{Tribute.tex}
\input{dedicate.tex}
\input{SSSUCertificate.tex}
\input{Declaration.tex}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{roman}
\listoffigures
\input{Ack.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\input{Abstract.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
%\listoftables
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{mystyle}
%\chapterfont{\color{Aquamarine}}
%\sectionfont{\color{MidnightBlue}}
%\subsectionfont{\color{RedViolet}}
%input your tex files using the input command
\input{intro.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\input{chapter1.tex}
\input{chapter2.tex}
\input{chapter3.tex}
\input{chapter4.tex}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
%create a bibiliograpgy file using jabref and input the file name below. In this case it is refs.bib
\bibliography{refs}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

thanks for the help and suggestions.

Comment: [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208)

Comment: [Headers of \chapters\* take the headers of their previous \chapter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78090)

Comment: @Johannes_B, Thanks !! The 2nd issue is resolved but the first and third is still unclear. The table of contents still starts the introduction chapter from page 3. And also if you can be little more down to earth regarding putting page numbers in acknowledgement and abstract ans incorporate the same in the table of contents, it will be useful. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue should be solvable by using the following after starting your mainmatter:

```
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

This resets the page number.

For the second issue, I would use the `titlesec` package to set the pagestyle of the chapter page:

```
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{plain}
```

This is necessary as the `\chapter` sets the plain pagestyle by default.

Comment: If `\mainmatter` would be used, the problem wouldn't occure. This is probably due to using `\pagenumbering` . The `pagestyle` matter is dealt with in the example code but probably overridden later. Nobody knows.

Comment: As far as I can see, `\mainmatter` is used in the code posted?

Comment: Oh yes, i am sorry. The manual toc entry is added at the wrong place.

Comment: Also, while I see that the chapter style is attempted dealt with in the code, the `titlesec` package might have more robust implementation? At least it has worked well for me for this issue in the past.

Comment: When editing the question the first time, i didn't notice the little note to the extra file. So when i looked at it i missed the actual document (which we don't know much bout, since it is hidden). Can you add that the manual `\addcontentsline` should come directly after the `chapter` command?

Comment: I don't know why this happend, when I used \setcounter{page}{0} just after \input(intro.tex), that the table of contents showed introduction chapter from page 1 as required. the second issue was solved by using \markboth{}{}. The third issue is still unresolved.

Comment: @Hirak Are you trusting yourself in always setting the page number manually or are you willing to place the `\addcontentsline` where it belongs and avoiding any manual interaction?

Comment: For the *third* issue: Open up a new question. Generally we have one question, one issue.

Comment: Till now I have been using \addcontentsline as the code will show, but for this I had to use the option I mentioned in the above comment