# "Contents" apears above Preface heading

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, books

The following code gives me a "Preface" and a "Prologue", but with, at the top of their respective pageS, the word `CONTENTS` (see screen capture bellow, for the Preface page). It's as if the "Preface" and the "Prologue" were still part of the document's contents section.

I can't figure out how to not have that word up there.
Thanks.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,letterpaper]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {TSTPT_Images/} }
%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\title{\Huge THIS IS MY TITLE}
\author{Name of author here}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{center}
\chapter*{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering Book One:\\Title of Book One}}
%\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{image}}
\end{center}
\clearpage

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Preface}
\section*{Preface}

Text here.

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Prologue}
\section*{Prologue}

Text here.

\cleardoublepage
\mainmatter
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Chapter The First}
\chapter*{Chapter The First}
\section{Title Uno}

Text here.

\cleardoublepage
\section{Title Dos}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Chapter The Second}
\chapter*{Chapter The Second}
\section{Title Tres}
Text for test.\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The intended structure of the document is not properly reflected by the sectioning commands. `\tableofcontents` is on the level of a chapter, whereas preface and prolog are `\section`s, hence they appear as sub-units of the table of contents. Use `\part` commands for dividing the document into sub-books. Moreover, your table of contents will be for the whole document, not only for the first book. There are packages for having several table of documents.

Comment: Is it intended to have several of these "books" in one document, each with a table of contents, or is the `chapter*{... Book One...}` intended as a subtitle-page?

Comment: I'd suggest being consistent with the `book` sectional units. Use `\chapter*` for your **Preface** and reformat the way the chapters look in the ToC (using something like [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)) rather than setting a chapter as a section.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Headers of `\chapter*` take the headers of their previous `\chapter`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78088/5764)

Comment: @gernot It is intended to have several books within one document, each with a TOC (so, an overall TOC at the beginning and then individual TOC per book). I find it convoluted too, but it's my friend's design so I'll stick to it for now. And thank you all for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\markright{}` after `\tableofcontents` and `\cleardoublepage` helps to remove the chapter title from the header. The page number stays in the header.

An alternative is `\thispagestyle{plain}` for the start pages of the sections in the front matter.

Also:

- `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` for unmarked links
- Section numbers like `0.1`, `0.2` are a bit strange, maybe this is the intension: Unnumbered chapters with independently numbered sections:

  ```
  \usepackage{remreset}
  \makeatletter
  \@removefromreset{section}{chapter}
  \makeatother
  \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
  ```
- The duplicate page anchor problem can be solved by:

  ```
  \begingroup
    \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
    \maketitle
  \endgroup
  ```
- The box problem of the "book title page" can be fixed by:

  ```
  \vspace*{50pt}
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \Huge\bfseries
    Book One:\\Title of Book One
    \par
    \thispagestyle{plain}
  \endgroup
  \clearpage
  ```
- Maybe some empty page(s) needs to be inserted in the beginning part to fix the page numbers. Odd numbered pages are right pages, even numbered pages are left pages.