# Problem with headings in a Latex "book "as document class

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I am using Latex for a thesis redaction and I am using 'book' as document class
The problem that I am facing is with the table of figures and the chapter just inserted after it, the "table of figure" remains marked as header in the next page which is the "Introduction" and I don't know how the header of "Table of figures" could be replaced with header: "Introduction" for the second page of the "Introduction" chapter.

This header problem is raised only in the mentioned case, all the other chapters' headers are normally inserted.

This is a part of the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\let\origdoublepage\cleardoublepage
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\origdoublepage}}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearemptydoublepage
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
   \lhead{}
   \chead{}
  \rhead{\fancyplain{}{\textit{\leftmark}}}


\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\myemptypage{
  \null
   \thispagestyle{plain}
%   \cleardoubleplainpage
   \addtocounter{page}{0}
   \newpage
  }
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}

%===============================================================================


%===============================================================================
%   Début du document
%===============================================================================

\begin{document}

%===============================================================================
%   Titre
%===============================================================================

\include{titre}
%===============================================================================
\frontmatter

%===============================================================================

\include{Remerciements}

\include{Dédicace}
\myemptypage
\include{Résumé}
\myemptypage

\include{Abstract}
\myemptypage
%===============================================================================
\include{res}
\myemptypage
 \tableofcontents
 \listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Liste des Tableaux}
\newpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Liste des Figures}
\myemptypage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Liste des abréviations}
\myemptypage

\include{acro}

\myemptypage
\mainmatter
\include{introduction}
\myemptypage
\end document
```

Comment: The problem was solved referring to:
// https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78088/headers-of-chapters-take-the-headers-of-their-previous-chapter/78090#78090

Comment: It would have helped if you had shown the code for the introduction.tex. --- GOM

Comment: Thank you though for your concern Peter Wilson